# Find one unique element in List with duplicates in Java

Tags: java, arrays, unique

We have list if Integers (or some another object) like:

```
[0, 0, 1, 1, ... , 777777, ... , 999999, 999999]
```

Java code:

```
List<Integer> ints = new LinkedList<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < 999999; i++) {
    ints.add(i); // add first value
    if (i!=777777){
        ints.add(i); // add duplicate value in not '5'
    }
}
```

I resolve this problem in that way:

```
Integer unique = null;
while (true) {
    unique = ints.get(0);
    ints.remove(0);
    if (ints.contains(unique)) {
        ints.remove(ints.indexOf(unique));
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
System.out.println(unique);// 777777
```

It takes about 30 ms. With ArrayList it works much longer.
Question is how to get one unique value (for example 777777) from this list in optimal (right/elegant/fastest) way.

Comment: 1. Sort the list 2. iterate and check each item vs. previous and next to see if it is unique.

Comment: If you know the elements come in pairs (except for the unique one), use binary search to find the border between where the pairs come in an even and then an odd index, and where they come in an odd and then an even index. Will work fast with `ArrayList`.

Comment: Do equal elements always come consecutively in the list?

Comment: There’s a difference between elegant and fast. Which do you prefer? In my ear 30 ms doesn’t sound like any problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your implementation is very inefficient since you run linear time operations such as `ints.contains(unique)` and `ints.indexOf(unique)` in a loop. Therefore your running time is `O(n^2)` in the worst case.

If the numbers are always sorted (as they are in your example), you can iterate once over the elements of the list a find the element `list.get(i)` which is not equals to `list.get(i-1)` and `list.get(i+1)`. This will take `O(n)`.

If the numbers are not always sorted you can sort them in `O(nlogn)` and proceed as before.

Or you can iterate over the numbers once, count the number of occurrences of each number (you can store the counts in a `HashMap`), and find the number whose count is 1. This will take `O(n)` regardless of whether the input list is sorted or not.

Answer (score 3):

Other than the `Set` solution given by the other answers, if you know that your duplicate elements only appear **twice** (or an even number of times) and there is only **one non-duplicate** number, you can XOR all of your values to find the unique one.

```
public int findUnique(int[] nums) { // Or (List<Integer> nums), it works also
    int xor = 0;
    for(int i : nums){
        xor ^= i;
    }
    return xor;
}
```

This solution is faster and shorter than the other solutions.

---

You could also do it in Java 8 style but it will be slower of course:

```
public int findUnique(int[] nums) {
    return Arrays.stream(nums)
            .reduce((acc,i) -> acc ^= i)
            .orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);
}
```

Comment: OK, so this might not be the most readable solution, but it is O(n) as time complexity and there is no space complexity besides the bookkeeping (xor and i in this example). I  had this question in an interview today and I think it's a pretty badass solution.

Comment: Is this solution take into account that the list is always order? Would this provide the desired outcome if the list is not order?

Comment: @Nate the order doesn't matter. xor is commutative so any order provides the same result.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong collection. List is not the right collection in this problem.
 You should use **HashSet** for this problem.

```
private void find(List<Integer> ints){
   HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
   for(int i=0;i<ints.size();i++){
       if(set.contains(i)){
          set.remove(i);
       }else{
          set.add(i);
       }
   }
   Iterator<Integer> itr = set.iterator();
   if(itr.hasNext()){
      System.out.println("Unique value is :"+itr.next());
   }else{
      System.out.println("There is no duplicated value");
   }
}
```

This approach only works for 2 and 1 counted list items. If you have same number for 3 times, this approach finds it as duplicated.

Sorting might be the answer but sorting has O(logn) at best, after that O(n) for finding the duplicated element. If you can create the hashset while creating the list this approach finds the duplicated element as O(1).

Answer (score 1):

First get the unique elements and then Use collections api's frequency method to get occurrences of duplicates

```
Set<String> uniqueSet = new HashSet<String>(list);

for (String temp : uniqueSet) {
    if(Collections.frequency(list, temp)==1) {
      System.out.println(temp);
    }

}
```

This will return unique elements from list.

Comment: Good idea, but it take's too much time.

Answer (score 0):

How about trying jdk8's streaming API like below:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class FiindUnique {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        Collection<String> list = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C");

        //solution 1
        List<String> distinctElements = list.stream().filter(name -> Collections.frequency(list, name) == 1).collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(distinctElements);

        //Solution 2

        List<String> distinctElements2 = list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(e -> e.getValue() == 1)
            .map(e -> e.getKey())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
         System.out.println(distinctElements2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Solution 1 looks really good but takes too much time. Second work faster.

Answer (score 0):

By doing a binary search to find the inversion point i.e. before the unique number even and odd index will have the same number, and after the unique number, odd and even will have the same number, so we can do a binary search to find the inversion point the the time complexity will be log(N)

Answer (score -1):

Do you assume the array is sorted?
This should probably be quicker.

```
HashSet<Integer> s = new HashSet<Integer>();

for ( Integer i : ints){
    if ( s.contains(i)){
        s.remove(i); // remove dups
    }
    else{
        s.add(i); //add uniques
    }
}

for ( Integer unique: s){
// should contain one value
    System.out.println(unique);// 777777
}
```